# Find Min-Max of: $P=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(ab+bc+ca)$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ are real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=5$ and $a \geq b \geq c$. Find the Min and Max value of:

$$P=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(ab+bc+ca)$$

Here is what I tried:

Have: $$P^2 = (a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2(ab+bc+ca)^2 \leq \frac{(a-c)^6}{16}(ab+bc+ca)^2$$

$$\leq \frac{{\left\{\left[\frac{2 \left(a-b\right)^{2}}{3}+\frac{2 \left(b-c\right)^{2}}{3}+\frac{2 \left(c-a\right)^{2}}{3}\right]\right\}}^{3}}{16}(ab+bc+ca)^2$$
$$=\frac{1}{216}t^3(10-t)^2=\frac{1}{216}(t^5-20t^4+100t^3)$$
Put: $$f(t) = \frac{1}{126}(t^5-20t^4+100t^3)$$ with $t \in [0;15]$.

Easy to check that: $$f(t)  \leq f(15) = \frac{3125}{8}$$
So get: $$|P| \leq \frac{25 \sqrt{10}}{4}$$

which leads to:

$$\frac{-25 \sqrt{10}}{4} \leq P \leq \frac{25 \sqrt{10}}{4}$$

But when I use wolfram to check, it said that the minimum is $-4$

Can anyone make the solution that leads to $-4$ please, thank you!